# Adding a ImageView to the MasterDetailFlow sample

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm very new in Android and I'm bulding a MasterDetailFlow application the problem is that I can't change the layout file (there is only the default TextView).
I want to add an ImageView and a MapView.

Please don't forget that I'm a beginner :D !

Thanks.

```
public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

public StationDetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_station_detail, container, false);
    if (mItem != null) {
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.station_detail)).setText(mItem.title);
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: can you add your sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto generated layout files will only contain a textview and you are therefor not able to add any new stull from the palette.

e.g

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/game_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".GameDetailFragment" />
```

If you add any other Layout around the generated stub, you will be able to modify and add new stuff within that layout.xml

example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/game_detail"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:context=".GameDetailFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```